# jQuery selector not working when a variable is used as selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use a jQuery selector with a variable as the class selector as shown in second code snippet below. While the first code snippet works perfectly, the second snippet throws an error that says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

**Question**:  What is wrong with the second code snippet? Its identical to first code snippet except for the variable of `rgFilterRow`. I tried escaping the double quotes in find part of second code snippet but still it gives the same error.

**Original Selector that works**

```
filterInputElement = $($(".rgFilterRow")[0].cells[columnIndex]).find("input[type='text']");
```

**New Selector with variable for selected class that does not work**

```
var filterRowClass = "rgFilterRow";
filterInputElement = $($("." + filterRowClass  + ")[0].cells[columnIndex]).find(\"input[type='text']\")";
```

**UPDATE**

The point to keep in mind when using variables in jQuery selector is that the  concatentation using one or more variables should be within the opening and closing parenthesis of the jQuery selector i.e. the parenthesis of jQuery selector should not be included in concatenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var filterRowClass = "rgFilterRow";
filterInputElement = $($("." + filterRowClass)[0].cells[columnIndex]).find("input[type='text']");
```

You don't need `\` and `+ "` after `filterRowClass` in `$()` selector.

Comment: I guess the point that I missed is  that concatenation should be done only within the open and close parenthesis of $ so the parenthesis are always outside the concatenated parts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update

```
filterInputElement = $($("." + filterRowClass  + ")[0].cells[columnIndex]).find(\"input[type='text']\")";
```

to

```
filterInputElement = $($("." + filterRowClass)[0].cells[columnIndex]).find("input[type='text']");
```